# How to identify a bike part for replacement?

Tags: chainring, electric-bike

Is there any website or way to find which bike parts I need to buy?

For example, following picture of chainring and there is no information on it to search on the internet.

[image]
[image]

I tried image but no luck. I tried searching by frame number and model but no luck.

---

I'm looking for a matching spider that will be attached to the motor.

Comment: You're actually holding 2 pieces there; a chainring (with the teeth) which is bolted to a [spider](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/22974/43557) (the bit in the middle with the arms).  Which one are you looking to replace?  The answer will depend on that.

Comment: May I suggest adding the number of bots and the distance between them to the search query?

Comment: What ojs is suggesting is to measure the distance between the *centre* of either opposite pair of bolts (across the middle of the spider) to find the "BCD" ([Bolt Circle Diameter](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/55802/43557)) of the chainring.  Then search for "4 bolt {distance} BCD chainring" assuming that it's a new chainring (and not a spider) that you need.  The chainring itself actually looks in pretty good shape, though, which is why I was wondering if you're trying to replace the spider instead.

Comment: @DavidW - I thought he was referring to roBOTS!

Comment: @DavidW  I'm looking for a matching spider that will be attached to the motor.

Comment: That may then depend on the type/brand of the motor. For example you may need to search "Bafang 4 bolt spider" if it were a bafang motor. Frame number and model generally mean very little when it comes to bikes. You're better off searching the brand and model name that is usually written on the top tube of the bike.

Comment: I'm guessing the inner spline has worn off which is why you want a replacement?  And the steel shaft of the motor is fine?  If you'd noticed this sooner it may have been saveable.  Also, have you over-powered the motor?  The extra torque may have exacerbated this, and you might prefer to choose a steel part over an aluminium part.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terminology index - a list of bike part names and cycling concepts](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts)